# Update a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, ado

How does the code below work? I've never seen an UPDATE done this way. I always do it this way:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

---

```
sqlText = "SELECT * FROM pricing WHERE pid=1"
rsx.Open sqlText, cnx, 1, 2

if Not rsx.EOF then

    rsx("new_us") = Request.Form("new_us")
    rsx("new_us_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("new_us_desc"))
    rsx("new_ca") = Request.Form("new_ca")
    rsx("new_ca_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("new_ca_desc"))
    rsx("new_int") = Request.Form("new_int")
    rsx("new_int_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("new_int_desc"))
    rsx("conv_us") = Request.Form("conv_us")
    rsx("conv_us_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("conv_us_desc"))
    rsx("conv_ca") = Request.Form("conv_ca")
    rsx("conv_ca_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("conv_ca_desc"))
    rsx("conv_int") = Request.Form("conv_int")
    rsx("conv_int_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("conv_int_desc"))
    rsx("ren_us") = Request.Form("ren_us")
    rsx("ren_us_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("ren_us_desc"))
    rsx("ren_ca") = Request.Form("ren_ca")
    rsx("ren_ca_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("ren_ca_desc"))
    rsx("ren_int") = Request.Form("ren_int")
    rsx("ren_int_desc") = Rtrim(Request.Form("ren_int_desc"))
    rsx.Update

end if

rsx.Close
cnx.Close

Set rsx = Nothing
Set cnx = Nothing
```

---

Thanks

Brett

Comment: Sorry, the title should be MS SQL table...Thanks

Comment: What kind of file is this in? It isn't just SQL it is SQL embedded in some other kind of code.

Comment: Looks like VB 5/6 or classic ASP (vbscript) to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you execute the query with `rsx.Open`. `cnx` is the connection to the db, parameter value 1 is `CursorType = adOpenKeyset` and parameter value 2 is `LockType = adLockPessimistic`.

```
sqlText = "SELECT * FROM pricing WHERE pid=1"
rsx.Open sqlText, cnx, 1, 2
```

`rsx` is a `Recordset` (com object) that holds the returned rows. `if Not rsx.EOF then` checks that you actually got at least one row, otherwise the edit will fail.

This `rsx("new_us") = Request.Form("new_us")` assign new values to fields in the `Recordset`.

Finally `rsx.Update` saves the modified fields to the db. The OLE DB Provider used by `cnx` builds the update statement that is sent to the database.

So basic work flow is:

1. Fetch a row from db
2. Modify row
3. Send the row back to db

Comment: Thanks to the both of you for the answers.  I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

This : http://www.w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_recordset.asp should help ;)

It is a ADO Recordset (not ADO.NET). Through the Recordset (rsx in this case), you have access to the fields of your query. By changing the value, you can update the database through the Update method.

Comment: Yes, it is classic ASP with the SQL embedded within an ASP page.

Comment: They started with a SELECT statement, checked to see that record existed and then updated the record.  Would this be considered the optimal way to perform an UPDATE?  Thanks  Brett

Comment: I don't know if it is the best way, but the great advantage is that we have no need to manage the implementation of the update. By cons, it's a fairly old technology now, it's better to turn to ADO.NET which is more efficient.